# OPEN GL ES 1.0. World coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es, picking, mouse-picking

For 3d-picking I planned to do this:

-Get touch coordinates (x, y)

-Choose vertex from vertex buffer of my model (xM, yM, zM).

-Then project by my own hands (xM, yM, zM) on the screen coords

**(xM, yM, zM) ---> (xP, yP, ...)**

and then check match (for example  sqrt((x - xP)^2 + (y - yP)^2) < SOME_EPS)

For projecting I saved Frustum Matrix in **mProjectionMatrix**:

```
gl.glFrustumf(-ratio / q, ratio / q, -1 / q, 1 / q, 1, 25);
Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio / q, ratio / q, -1 / q, 1 / q, 1, 25);
```

and saved Transform coordinates in **mAccRotation**:

```
gl.glLoadMatrixf(mAccRotation, 0);
```

So the testing function turned into this:
(TESTIFY_VERT is one of ones in my model)

```
public void touch(float x, float y){

    float TESTIFY_VERT[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.5f, 1.0f}; //first vert in L0
    float Resulted[] = new float[4];
    float rMatrix[] = new float[16];

    Matrix.multiplyMM(rMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mAccRotation, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(Resulted, 0, rMatrix, 0, TESTIFY_VERT, 0);
}
```

So I tried to use **Resulted[0], Resulted[1]** as (xP, yP)

and tried to use **(Resulted[0] + 1) * ( WIDTH / 2.0f ), (-Resulted[1] + 1) * ( HEIGHT / 2.0f )**

And this don't work. Why?
Can you give an advice?

PS I have seen ALL such a questions and they don't answer my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are missing perspective divide. Divide *Resulted[0]*, *Resulted[1]* by  *Resulted[3]* and use the ratios as *(xP, yP)* i.e.:

```
float xP = Resulted[0] / Resulted[3];
float yP = Resulted[1] / Resulted[3];
```

Comment: for the tip, I was struggling in a similar issue. Thanks sir, you saved my day :)